# Change of the default 2x tile size into 3x tile size when zooming the image one level in OpenSeaDragon

Tags: javascript, openseadragon

Width and height of the tile is doubled with each level of zoom by default. Is there a way to change this behaviour?

**Currently:**

```
Level 11 (max) -> 32x32 px
Level 10       -> 64x64 px
...
```

**Is there a way to change this default behaviour for:**

```
Level 11 (max) -> 32x32 px
Level 10       -> 96x96 px
...
```

Instead of 1 tile becoming the size of 4 tiles, can 1 tile become the size of 9 tiles which each zooming step?

Comment: What kind of tile source are you using? Is it custom? It should be possible to implement a tile source like this by overriding the following methods https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon/blob/master/src/tilesource.js#L252-L316

Comment: Yes, it is custom. Thanks for the hint!